# th:href with a list, dynamically construct links in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

**The following situation is set:**

I use thymeleaf with spring mvc.
I have a form with a multibox, the values of the multibox are passed as string array as request param:

```
@RequestParam String[] selectedTypes
```

The request is a http get.

**The problem:**

In the rendered view after this request I want to construct the same get URL.
I couldn't find a solution, where I can iterate over the selectedTypes and construct the URL. I ended up with building a map an pass it over the ModelView and then get the values from the map. But this solution looks not so elegant.

```
  <a th:href="@{'/part1/part2/' + ${part2Id} + '/part3/' + ${part3Id} + '/type/' + ${type} + '.html'
               (
               selectedtypes=${selectedTypesMap.get('TYPE1')},
               selectedtypes=${selectedTypesMap.get('TYPE2')},  
               selectedtypes=${selectedTypesMap.get('TYPE3')},
               selectedtypes=${selectedTypesMap.get('TYPE4')}
               )}" 
     class="cssclazz" 
     th:text="${year}" />
```

With this solution I have to know the amount of types. if there is no type in the map empty parameters will be sent.

Comment: I'd suggest you create your own dialect/utilities object for the dynamic parameter list, as this is not possible with the standard Thymeleaf URL syntax.